# Converting a 1D array to a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, split

Got an array:

```
String[] array = song.split("");
[W, U, B, W, U, B, A, B, C, W, U, B]
```

I need to convert it in two dimension:

```
String[][] arr = new String[4][3];
[[W, U, B], [W, U, B], [A, B, C], [W, U, B]]
```

Below code:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[j].length; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = array[j];
    }
}
```

gives the result:

```
[[W, U, B], [W, U, B], [W, U, B], [W, U, B]]
```

How to get:

```
[[W, U, B], [W, U, B], [A, B, C], [W, U, B]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the wrong value to `arr[i][j]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <arr.length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <arr[j].length ; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = array[i * arr[j].length + j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single loop, iterating over `array`, and calculating the indexes into `arr` using division and remainder operators.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    arr[i / 3][i % 3] = array[i];
```

*Test*

```
String song = "WUBWUBABCWUB";
String[] array = song.split("");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

String[][] arr = new String[4][3];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    arr[i / 3][i % 3] = array[i];
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

*Output*

```
[W, U, B, W, U, B, A, B, C, W, U, B]
[[W, U, B], [W, U, B], [A, B, C], [W, U, B]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `arr[i][j] = array[j]`. The variable `j` should continue. Instead use a variable that doesn't assign `0` again when the outer loop pass to the next iteration because the inner loop do the assing `j = 0` again. Use another counter outside of the loops to maintain the value, in this case `k`.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String[] array = { "W", "U", "B", "W", "U", "B", "A", "B", "C", "W", "U", "B" };
        String array2[][] = new String[4][3];

        // One dimension array into a two dimension array.
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i  <array2.length ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2[j].length; j++)
            {
                array2[i][j] = array[k++];
            }
        }

        // Print 1 dimension array.
        System.out.println("array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }

        // Print 2 dimension array.
        System.out.println("\n\narray2:");
        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(array2[i][j] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process this array as follows:

```java
String[] arr = "WUBWUBABCWUB".split("");

String[][] arr2d = IntStream
        .iterate(0, i -> i < arr.length, i -> i + 3)
        .mapToObj(i -> Arrays
                .stream(arr, i, Math.min(i + 3, arr.length))
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr2d));
// [[W, U, B], [W, U, B], [A, B, C], [W, U, B]]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Copying a 1d array to a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65635101/14940971)</sup>